# Web app showing errors when custom authentication provider included

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, password-encryption

Hello I have a custom authentication provider but when I tried to include a password encoder in my authentication manager, It shows an error that I can not have child elements when used with ref attribute. Here's my problem code....

'

```
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider">

    <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use custom authentication provider, you need to set password encoder on the referenced bean.
Here is example for xml-config:

```
<bean id="authProvider"
      class="me.sample.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    ... other properties ...
</bean>
```

And, as error suggests, you need to remove  element from `<security:authentication-provider/>`

```
<security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
```